# How to know what will be rollbacked?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Although migrate rollback is trivial, but it could lead to a catastrophe on production db.

I am sure that in my case it will rollback the last migration file only, but can't I double check this fact?

Isn't there a command that will tell me which migration files will be rolled back when I run the migrate:rollback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such command, but you can [create your own command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-commands) (it's really a pretty simple task, will took like 5 minutes) and use simple query to a migrations table, like:

```
public function handle()
{
    $lastMigration = \DB::table('migrations')->orderBy('batch', 'DESC')->first();
    $lastBatch = $lastMigration->batch; // last batch ID
    $migrations = \DB::table('migrations')->where('batch', $lastBatch);
    foreach ($migrations as $migration) {
        $this->info($migration->migration); // output current migration name to cli
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure... no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the 'batch' number in the batch column in the migrations table in your database. The latest batch of migrations will be rolled back.